# How can i store 12 bit values in an ushort?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got a stream coming from a camera that is set to a 12 bit pixel format.
My question is how can i store the pixel values in an array?

Before i was taking pictures with a 16 bit pixel format, but now i changed to 12 bit and I get the same full size image displayed four images on the screen next to one another I used to store the values in an ushort array then.

When i have the camera set to 8 bit pixel format I store the data in a byte array, but what should I use when having it at 12 bit?

Comment: Short answer: use bitwise operations to fetch the upper or lower 4 bits of incoming bytes and combine them into `ushort`

Comment: That depends on what you intend to do with it. If you simply want to store them in an arbitrary data format, size might be an issue (pack 'em tight). If you want to work with individual pixels, using a full int might be faster, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment, we can process the incoming stream in 3-byte "chunks", each of which give 2 pixels.

```
// for a "chunk" of incoming array a[0], a[1], a[2]
ushort pixel1 = ((ushort)a[0] << 4) | ((a[1] >> 4) & 0xFF);
ushort pixel2 = ((ushort)(a[1] & 0xFF) << 4) | a[2];
```

(Assuming big-endian)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think that there is a more efficient way of doing the bitwise operations because right now I have to do a for loop through the whole buffer. I used to do it with     Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer.Array, 0, PixelsArray, 0, PayloadSize);             which is very efficient in terms of time. Here's some more information to how the pixels are coming from the camera [link](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/796839/Basler-Gige-Vision-Cameras.html?page=163)

Comment: Why do think that looping through the buffer is inherently less efficient than calling a ready-made library function? As I see it the only way to improve is to make use of SIMD and/or inline assembly, although I'm unsure about the effort-to-gain ratio of the latter.

Answer (score -2):

The smallest memory size you can allocate is one byte (8 bits) that means that if you need 12 bits of data to store one pixel in your frame array you should use `ushort`. And leave the 4 bits alone . That’s why it’s more efficient to design these kind of stuff with numbers from the pow of two
(1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128.. etch)